# How to use the arguments from the list to be used as input variable for python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to run/loop a script called news.py using subprocess call for the list. The script needs few arguments. I want to use the arguments from the list I just printed.

List looks like this:-

```
[{'name': 'sp', 'version': 'v1.1.0'},
{'name': 'path', 'version': 'v0.4.0'},
{'name': 'test', 'version': 'v1.5.1'},
{'name': 'err', 'version': 'v0.9.1'}]

 List = []
 for i in reversed(List):
     names = print(i['name'])
     versions = print(i['version'])
     subprocess.call(['python3','news.py', names, versions], shell=True)
```

Its not taking names and versions as argument and the script news.py is
complaining about this error: the following arguments are required: --m-name, --m-version.

Can anyone suggest the way forward would be really appreciated.

Comment: But, `names = print(...` means that `names` is `None`. Please update your question with the full text of the error output you are seeing.

Comment: Could you please show the code inside `news.py` script?

Comment: It's easier to run and debug this here - https://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 0):

The example assigns the return of `print()`, which is `None`, to the variables `names` and `versions`

try this instead:

```py
names = i['name']
versions = i['version']
```

Comment: this also doesn't give me anything else than this {'name': 'path', 'version': 'v0.4.0'}, . I want name=path and version = v0.4.0 and use these name and version in subprocess.call as arguments